# Form field not getting stored in Django User model

Tags: python, django

I have a signup form which I have defined below

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    display_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, help_text='Please provide a display name for your profile')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'display_name')
```

In the views.py, I handle the signup process

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


@csrf_exempt
def signup_users(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            display_name = form.cleaned_data.get('display_name')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')

            user.set_password(raw_password)
            user.display_name = display_name
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            print("signup authencticate", user)
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

The user is able to signup successfully however their `display_name` doesn't get stored in the django User model.Even in the django admin, I do not see the field `display_name`.I have even performed a query like `serializers.serialize("json",User.objects.filter(username=username))` but even here it shows every other field except the `display_name`.

What am I  doing wrong?

Comment: The `display_name` is not a column of the `User` model. So *where* should it be stored?

Comment: You will need to change the user model, if you want to construct an extra table, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Well quite simply the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model has not field named `display_name` so of course it doesn't get saved. If you want to add fields to your User model you'll have to [provide a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Oh I get it now.As there any way I can add a new field to the existing Django user model?

Comment: @SouvikRay well actually yes but that will be __much__ more complicated than providing your own model (as explained in the doc I linked to) AND it will freaks any django programmer out AND it's garanteed to break one way or another.  Your choice <g>

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html